# Kalman filter with spatial derivatives

Tags: kalman-filter

Is it possible to model a system for Kalman filter with spatial (not time) derivatives? In my application the x_n can be expressed as

```
x_n+1 = x_n + x'_n * d
x'_n+1 = x'_n
```

where x' is the spatial derivative of x, i.e differentiation with respect to distance. Can these make a valid model for Kalman filter? The `d` is an input/parameter without any noise, like a control input.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any problems that you would encounter, and I don't think that the filtering process would change at all. The dynamics would just be taking you to the next step, rather than the next *time* step. The measurements aren't dependent on time, so there will be no changes there.